# Morphia Decalration of query on object does not type-cast properly

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

So I'm working with Morphia and Mongo trying to write some basic queries in Java.
Here's a basic example:

```
final Query<Flight> query = datastore.createQuery(Flight.class);
final List<Flight> answer = query.filter("Miles>", 100).asList();
```

The editor/compiler I'm using is giving me an error that says "cannot cast Query to Query" on the first line. As a result the second line can't execute either. We tried typecasting datastore.createQuery(Flight.class) but that did not work. Do you guys know the solution to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In the code it is not able to recognized Query as a class. The solution is in the header of the code import the Query class like so:

```
import org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query;
```